# c illegal else without matching if

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

Okay, this might be a shot in the dark.

I'm writing a software harness to test some code for an application using usb data transfer. I can't post the code online and I can't give a lot of specifics on exactly what the code does but I can post the loop that is throwing this bizarre error.

When I attempt to compile the source file that this loop exists in, I get a number of syntax errors (that you can see don't apply) and this error `error C2181: illegal else without matching if` (which you can also see doesn't apply). I know that this code works in it's normal operating environment, but I do need to test it for any possible loopholes. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the loop in particular. It deals with determining if a message received from usb is complete:

```
void _usb_rx_complete(_message_union_t *buf_ptr)
{
    if(buf_ptr == &s_msg_buf[0].buffer)
    {
        s_msg_buf[0].is_complete = 0;
        s_msg_buf[0].byte_index = 0;
    }
    else if(buf_ptr == &s_msg_buf[1].buffer)
    {
        s_msg_buf[1].is_complete = 0;
        s_msg_buf[1].byte_index = 0;
    }
}
```

Usually this is caused by semi-colons after the if statement but I'm clean there. In addition, if I comment out this loop, I don't get any of the above errors so I don't think it's an issue with another part of the program. The syntax errors are `error C2059: syntax error : '=='` and`error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'` within both if and else segment...Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check you've closed all your braces properly in the code that precedes this.

Comment: Yup, everything before this is closed up :\

Comment: Comment and compile until you find the exact line(s).

Comment: Might be worth trying to comment out the body of this method and compile, and see if you get any strange errors. Mgiht also want to paste the real code in to a nice editor that can beautify/tab out the text to make sure it's free of stray braces. Perhaps there's a stray brace in an imported .h file?

Comment: The error is in the "else if" line specifically. I'm not sure why though. If I comment out the "else if" line or segment there are just syntax errors (still not sure why but those worry me less than the illegal else one)

Comment: Looks like a `#define` problem.

Comment: Are you by chance using any macros? Perhaps one is injecting a stray brace.

Comment: @StealthRabbi there are no implementer-defined methods for this class. the software wasn't made with any special classes, just tons of structs.

Comment: nope, not using macros. this is really stumping me. going over it and it's headers with a fine tooth comb again (this is about 3x now)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson my buf_ptr is done with a #define. Could that be the problem? Any idea how to fix it? I'm no expert.

Comment: @katrijnn How is it defined?

Comment: That's almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. I had it defined like a constant when it was a ptr >.< Thanks

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Could you please post that as an aswer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has no obvious syntax error but the compiler still gives syntax errors as output, that usually points to a preprocessor related problem. Since posting your entire source code is obviously a problem, here are some pointers how to locate them;

To begin with, check any `#define` or macro defined in the file, or symbol in the failing expression which you know is a macro.

If that does not help with finding the problem, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you how to enable preprocessor output to a file in Visual Studio, inspecting that output that will almost always help with finding the problem.